# Create and Send custom Iq from ejabberd 15.07

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I am using ejabberd 15.07 and i want to send a custom iq packet from server on user_send_packet hook, do i need to add or register handler and how can i create iq packet ?

Comment: Do you have some example code you tried ?

Comment: No i have no idea or sample code that i tried to do that and would it be affecting other modules on server ?

Comment: *IQ stanza* is a request/response mechanism which for example should be requested by client and answered by server. If you want to initially send a packet from server to client without any request, you should consider *Message stanza* and use `ejabberd_router:route/3` function.